# Using whenever gem with sinatra

Tags: ruby, cron, sinatra, whenever

```
#config/scheduler.rb

set :output, 'log/cron.log'

every 1.minutes do
  rake 'reports:generate'
end
```

When I run `crontab -l` I get the following output:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd <path-to-app> bundle exec rake reports:generate --silent >> log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

First off, it seems to use my `system ruby` which is `1.8.7`, is there a way to change this?

Secondly, the task is not run, but the only thing that shows up in my `cron.log` is the following:

```
Your Ruby version is 1.8.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

I've tried `puts` to the log with no success, so I have basically no idea what's going on. It seems the task is being initiated, but then fails without anything being written to the log. I have no idea how to go about debugging this, so please help.

I'm on OS X, and my application is running on Sinatra.

**edit**: I'm using `rbenv` to manage my ruby versions, so I guess I have to tell the cron job to load rbenv somehow? When I `cd` into the app's folder and run `ruby -v` I get

```
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
```

Comment: you have the current ruby version is 1.8.7, switch it to 2.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem was with `rbenv`, and not necessarily `sinatra` or `whenever`. This solved my problem:

```
#schedlue.rb
command "cd #{Dir.pwd} && RACK_ENV=#{environment} rbenv exec bundle exec rake reports:generate"
```

By adding `rbenv exec` we successfully loaded the correct ruby version before running the rake task.